# Olly Debugger Linux not functioning

Tags: reverse-engineering, debugging

In Kali Linux whenever I open a binary in Olly Debugger after compiling the c source file, it gives an error:

"The file is not a valid PE file."

No debugging takes place thereafter. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` complies to the ELF format. PE is for Windows Executable files.

Use a Linux debugger. Something like `gdb` is fine.

Or cross-compile the c file to a Windows one (if that suits your use case)

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format for binaries.

Windows uses primarily the [PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

They are distinct. Olly is made for Windows binaries and does not understand ELF files.

[GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is a good debugger for Linux.